# MySQL join tables and extract data

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL I want to extract columns from two different tables

like I want title from table1 and body from table2

I am trying

```
SELECT `title` from node INNER JOIN  `body` from node_revisions
```

it gives error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from node_revisions
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: You need to specify which columns to join on. For example `select title from node inner join body on (node.id=body.node_revisions)`. I don't know what your table schema is, or what the second "from" refers to. If you can post the table schemas and what columns you want to join on, we can help you with the query.

Comment: I am simply using phpmyadmin 

`title` is column from table `Node`
and `Body` is column from table `node_revisions`

Comment: Okay, so I just want to be clear that you're trying to select the `title` and `body` column from `node` and `node_revisions`, right? So the piece that you're missing now, is which columns the table should be joined by. For example, your node table might have an `id`, and your node_revisions might have a `node` or `node_id` column. You need to join "on" those columns. So if the record you want to get the title from has an `id` of 1, then the node_revisions table would have a `node_id` of 1 as well.

Comment: they both have `nid` and `vid` can you please write a statement that i can run?

Comment: See the answer from P. Soutikevich for more details. It's important that you understand how to do a join, and how to do it efficiently. However, the query that you're looking for is likely: `SELECT node.title, node.body FROM node INNER JOIN node_revisions ON (node.nid = node_revisions.nid)`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to know what your *foreign key* is and what the *primary key*. The foreign key is used to **link** 2 tables together.

> A *foreign key* is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that refers to the *primary key* in another table. The table containing the *foreign key* is called the child table, and the table containing the *primary* key is called the referenced or parent table. You can check this great site for how to make a foreign key: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

I don't know how your tables were created, but if they can be linked together by an *INNER JOIN*, which means that there must be matching values in both tables, then this is what would give you the results you want:

`SELECT node.title AS title, node_revisions.body AS body
 FROM node
 INNER JOIN node_revisions ON node.FOREIGNKEY = node_revisions.PRIMARYKEY;`

I hope this helps you. You should do more research before asking such basic questions. All questions you might have about MySQL syntax, can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Hope this helps you

Comment: If you are using phpmyadmin, you can easily make columns foreign keys, primary keys, unique, auto-increment etc, by using their GUI. Just with a click of a button, no need to use queries for that.